# Spring Data JPA, @NamedQuery and Sort together

Tags: spring, spring-data, named-query

I'm trying to use @NamedQuery and Sort together, but it isn't working, I get error "No property * found for type" (If I use exactly same code without Sort parameter, or with Pageable, then it works fine). Here are my code snippets.

```
    @Entity
    @NamedQuery(
            name = "GenerateProductXmlInput.findByFilter",
            query = "select gpxi from GenerateProductXmlInput as gpxi where " +
                    "lower(coalesce(gpxi.shop.name, '')) like lower(concat('%', :filterShopName, '%')) and " +
                    "lower(coalesce(gpxi.locale.language, '')) like lower(concat('%', :filterLocaleLanguage, '%')) and " +
                    "lower(coalesce(gpxi.currency.name, '')) like lower(concat('%', :filterCurrencyName, '%')) and " +
                    "lower(coalesce(gpxi.customerGroup.name, '')) like lower(concat('%', :filterCustomerGroupName, '%'))"
    )
    public class GenerateProductXmlInput implements Serializable {
```

---

```
Page<GenerateProductXmlInput> findByFilter(
        @Param("filterShopName") String filterShopName,
        @Param("filterLocaleLanguage") String filterLocaleLanguage,
        @Param("filterCurrencyName") String filterCurrencyName,
        @Param("filterCustomerGroupName") String filterCustomerGroupName,
        Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: If you use Spring Data JPA you don't really need named queries. Instead of the named query, you can put a Spring Data [@Query](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) annotation on your `findByFilter` method with the query.

Comment: Jasper, if this was the case, there would be no explanation of how to use named queries in Spring Data documentation. I'm using them because I need 3 methods with same query string, one without anything, one with sort and one with pageable and I don't want to repeat same query three times in @Query

Comment: I didn't say you cannot use named queries; but there is an alternative available that you could try out. But ok, you have a valid reason for not using the `@Query` annotation.

Comment: Jasper, I'm always using Query anotation, just in this case I need something reusable. One option maybe would be to use same final String in three Query-s, but I don't want to do it like that, because I think named queries are exactly for this and maybe there is bug in spring data that Sort doesn't work with it.